# What is the Difference between these two sentences?

Tags: difference

I got confused between these two sentences:

Are you having internet connection? 
Do you have internet connection?

Can any one explain me.

Comment: I prefer _Do you have access to internet_ or_ Do you have internet connection_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you having internet connection can convey the message as 'Yes you do have internet connection, have access to it, but do you have it now?' After all, you may have access to it but the internet may be down or unavailable.

*Do you have internet connection?* seems to be asking that if you have internet access at all

Comment: *Are you having an internet connection* - can **also** mean 'do you have it...' if you don't dig it deep! In a normal (informal?) conversation, it's *absolutely* fine.

Comment: @MaulikV I never said it was _NOT FINE_. Please this Amit Saini is new to Stack Exchange. Don't discourage him. If i could comment on the question post I would.

Comment: Just to warn you, "Are you having internet connection" is not idiomatic (natural sounding to a native speaker) and may confuse some people. A better alternative is to ask the opposite - "Are you having internet connection problems?" This is idiomatic and you will be more easily understood.

Comment: Understood and agreed Colin Day.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is grammatically incorrect. The second sentence is correct if you add the indefinite article "an":

> Do you have an internet connection?

You could restate this in several ways:

> Do you have a connection to the internet?
>
> Are you connected to the internet?
>
> Do you have internet access?

All of these sentences mean the same thing.

Comment: i really appreciate your answer.